# Sorting objects on a user defined circular linked list, based on a field

Tags: java, object, linked-list, compare

So I have implemented these three classes, `ListNode` , `LinkedList` and `Book` . Class Book is as below:

```
class Book{
    int price;
    String name;
}
```

`LinkedList` contains `add()` method(that adds a book) and `display()`. I need to add another method to this class, that can sort a list containing books based on their name. How can i do this, since I cannot use `Collections.sort`?
This is the method sort I've done, but I don't know what kind of condition should I use, to decide if I should swap elements or not:

```
    public void sortList(SortList<Book> l) {

            Node current = head, index = null;
            E temp;
            if (head == null) {
                System.out.println("List is empty");
            } else {
                do {
                    index = current.next;
                    while (index != head) {
//if we had to sort integers would be if(current.data>index.data), then swap
                        if (???) {
                            temp = current.data;
                            current.data = index.data;
                            index.data = temp;
                        }
                        index = index.next;
                    }
                    current = current.next;
                } while (current.next != head);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show your attempt. There are lots of examples out there on how a linked list can be sorted. Try it. If you get into a specific problem doing so, then focus your question on that.

Comment: But did you look up any sorting methods for linked lists? Even if you get that comparison to work, you would spend O(n) on sorting, and that obviously cannot be right. A good comparison-based sort has an average complexity of O(nlogn). Just research sorting of linked lists, and implement one of the algorithms you find.

Comment: Thats not the aim of my school subject. Maybe later i will study data structures including their complexity or other factors. But the aim of my subject is to just learn the logic behind a problem, and solve it in any way.

Comment: You may have misunderstood my comment. I am saying your algorithm could never be a correct sorting algorithm, because if it was, you would have written the best sorting algorithm ever, breaking all records, sorting a list with just one sweep and at most n-1 swaps. So that is why I urge you to research the subject. A simple internet search will quickly lead you to example code. For instance, implement bubble sort, selection sort, merge sort, or quick sort, tailored to be used with linked lists.

Comment: Okay, i will try, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic thing would be to make the `Book` class [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) and then compare the two `Book` instances. If you can't do that, you could still extract the names and compare them, since `String`s are `Comparable`s:

```java
if (current.data.name.compareTo(index.data.name) > 0) {
    // perform the swap
```

Comment: But doesnt current.data (for example) have 2 values in it? An integer and a String. How would compare method know what to compare? I also tried current.data.name but id doesnt work.

Comment: @EveeKay oops! I meant to compare the `name`s inside the `data`, mea culpa. Edited and fixed.

Comment: As i said before, it doesnt work unfortunately. I dont know what im doing wrong